# Size of MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

How does .NET's `MessageBox` determine its size relative to the resolution of the screen on which it is displayed?

I am writing a slightly more flexible dialog window for a WPF application. The layout of the window is layed out in a Grid:

```
+-----------------
| auto: Header      // A header for the dialog.
+-----------------
| auto: Content     // can be any FrameworkElement.
+-----------------
| auto: BottomPanel // With buttons <OK>, <Cancel>, <Delete>, etc. 
+-----------------
```

The `Content`cell can be VERY large. In one of my use cases, the user wants to delete *x* elements from a list. The elements are then listed in the confirmation dialog. If there are many (let's say 50+) elements, the window can get large—too large for my taste.

What I would like is a function that determines the `MaxHeight`and `MaxWidth`properties of the dialog window from the current screen in a way that mimics Microsoft's own `MessageBox`dialog.

PS: I invoke the message dialog with the following `static` method:

```
// MessageDialog class
public static object Show(
        Window owner, 
        FrameworkElement content,
        string title,
        string header,
        params MessageDialogButton[] buttons
        );
/* The MessageDialogButton class has the following properties: 
 * Text, ReturnValue, IsDefault, IsCancel. The class produces 
 * System.Windows.Controls.Button objects that when clicked 
 * return the value of their ReturnValue property--which is then
 * returned by MessageDialog::Show(...)
 */
```

PPS: To determine the screen on which to display the dialog, the screen on which the `MessageDialog` window's `Owner` is located. As a fallback, the first (primary) screen is used.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but you may be interested in checking out [WindowsAPICodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) which gives you easy access to Vista+ TaskDialog, which basically is something like more agile and better looking MessageBox. Works on Vista+ only though, but maybe it will suit your needs.

Comment: This is always the stumbling block for anybody that tries to replace MessageBox.  Its auto-scaling is non-trivial to implement yourself.  Stop thinking about it as a message box, start thinking about it as just a regular window.  Scrollbars and allowing the user to resize the window are normal.

Comment: Thanks to Kragen's answer and Hans Passant's comment, I've come up with a solution: the window's max width and height are 5/8ths of the width of the screen and 2/3rds of its height. The content gets wrapped in a `ScrollViewer that allows the user to scroll the content if it gets too large. It's not exactly what I wanted, but I don't want to make lots of code to compute the layout multiple times simply to get the size of the message window.

Comment: For my own standard windows forms applications I have just written a replacement for MessageBox that is resizable. You can download it here and use it like a standard MessageBox:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601900/FlexibleMessageBox-A-flexible-replacement-for-the

Regards, Jörg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't going to find anything like that documented, however [according to Raymond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/24/10178386.aspx) (outdated link, this [link is more recent](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110624-00/?p=10343)) in Windows Vista the message box algorithm determined the width of the message box by choosing the smallest of the following which resulted in a box that fits in the working area:

- The width of the longest line
- 278 DLU ([Dialog units](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cf904ef5-ab22-46e3-8f95-0832a1810823/))
- 5/8 of the width of the working area
- 3/4 of the width of the working area
- 7/8 of the width of the working area

(I interpred this to mean that (for example) the width will be 5/8th of the width of the working area unless this results in the dialog which is taller than the height of the working area, in which case it will use a wider width).

This should at least give you some pointers for choosing a maximum width that doesn't look out of place.

As far as I am aware the message box doesn't have a maximum height, but I imagine a similar algorithm would work nicely.

If your dialog genuinely is very large then you might want to consider just making the dialog resizable / maximizable. (I'm not a fan of dialogs that display lists that are too large but don't allow you to resize the dialog to a more suitable size).

Comment: Why the last 3? The smallest of these is always 5/8 of the width of the working area, unless the width is negative.

Comment: @Jakob I also found the wording odd, but I think it is to account for the possibility that the dialog might end up being too tall for the working area, in which case a wider dialog width will be chosen.